# Relation between mass of gas, mass of stars and dark matter halo mass

Tags: galaxy, space, dark-matter, mass

As we all know that Mass of the galaxy can be written as the sum of the mass of gas(M<sub>g</sub>), the mass of stars (M<sub>s</sub>), and mass of dark matter halo(M<sub>h</sub>), as

M(galaxy)=M<sub>g</sub>+M<sub>h</sub>+M<sub>s</sub>,

But is there any formula which relates M<sub>g</sub> and M<sub>h</sub> and, M<sub>h</sub> and M<sub>s</sub>??

Does anybody know?

Comment: @pela actually i'm in search of the formula which relates mass of gas with mass of halo, and mass of star with mass of halo, does there exists any such formula?

Comment: As discussed in the linked answer, there isn't a _single_ formula, since the answer depends on the redshift, the mass range, the galaxy type, etc, as well as on which data/simulation you trust the most. But check out [Behroozi et al. (2013)](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013ApJ...770...57B), that's a good paper with several of the relations you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 0):

M(Galaxy) = Ms+Mh
_________ > M¹ :Mh¹ = M(Galaxy)
Mg+Ms
let say :
mass of star + mass of halo =assume as 1 terminology of process

mass of galaxy + mass of star = assume as 1 terminology of process to derive the mass of halo.
we are not given the amount,so this theories would be a posible ways to collect data for mass of halo.

create second terminology as M¹to support the terminology of Halo.

coz its happen in the galaxy itself.
Mass of Halo need to derive first in order to get posible
formula for range of star and mass of matter.
(Mh¹) = to M(Galaxy)

---

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about what this means and how it's derived?

Comment: @Ryukiaz MaxHebe can you write the answer more clearly?

Comment: i came out with an idea to derive possible unit count for mass halo.